# Windows Phone emulator 8.1 await InvokeScriptAsync silent crash?

Tags: windows-phone-8, async-await, windows-phone-8-emulator

Why this piece of code crash silently my windows pone 8.1 emulator? If not the first time click it till it will do it (second or third time).

```
private async void MainPage_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
{
    var result = await WebViewControl.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { document.location.href" });
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: You are setting `e.Handled` after the event handler returns. Try swapping the order of those two lines.

Comment: Yes that definitely prevents the app from crashing. But I don’t understand why? Could you provide some explanation or link to read? Also I need to take action based on the “result” variable is there any way to do it? Many thanks. @StephenCleary

Comment: The `await` actually causes the event handler to exit. I have an [async intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) on my blog if you're new to `async`. There isn't a good way to do asynchronous work synchronously, but if you post more details I can suggest some approaches.

Comment: @StephenCleary. Here is the problem...
Context: You have a single page app which relies on hash fragments for routing inside the WebView.
Problem: if you call webViewControll.GoBack() the WebView ignores all the hash fragments and return back to the plain URL (without the hash fragment).
Example: 
Hompage: www.example.com
Navigation1:  www.example.com -> www.example.com/#!/about
Navigation2: www.example.com/#!/about -> www.example.com/#!/contact
if i call GoBack() the WebView loads: www.example.com instead of: www.example.com/#!/about

Comment: @StephenCleary. So what I am trying to achieve is to handle navigation with the webapplication (inside the WebView) from native code ( var result = await WebViewControl.InvokeScriptAsync("windowsPhoneGoBack", null);). When I send the goback command to the webapp the web app returns whether it went back or not and then I am able to set the handled = true/false

Comment: Wouldn't a JavaScript history library work better?